# How to import CA for WSDL client generate purpose?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I've been given an WSDL file and ask me to create a JAVA client via it, so I run eclipse 4.5.2, created an empty Dynamic web project, import that WSDL into that project, and right click:

1. Web Services->Generate Client
2. Set configuration: Tomcat 7.0, Apache Axis
3. Click "Finish" and pop up exception: PKIX building path failed

So I look inside that WSDL, it contains some links that need to connect to our test service:

```
<soap:address location="https://example.com/testwebservice.svc" />
```

I looked around the Stackoverflow and seem like I need to import the CA from that HTTPS service site. But I don't know how to "Import" that CA while codes are not generated.

Please tell me how to solve this problem so I can move on to my development, thanks!

=====================

## Update

After I imported that CA to my cacerts, this problem still remain? this is weird since I exported all CA that this WSDL will connect to via browser (and keytool keep telling me that this CA already existed after my first import).

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'https://example.com/CPP/download/xsd0.xsd', relative to 'file:/D:/project/java_client/java_client.wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'https://example.com/CPP/download/xsd0.xsd', relative to 'file:/D:/project/java_client/java_client.wsdl'.: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.ibm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of steps involved to consume this service.

1. Get/Extract certificate of exposed service. This can be done by asking developers of that service to provide certificate or you can visit the service using browser and extract the certificate if that is possible.
2. Locate java's default Trust store. Java/JRE ships with global trust store located in Java installation. Find the cacerts file. This file should be available in /jre/lib/security.
3. Import the certificate in to trust store. Import certificate of webservice in cacerts file using keytool command.

   keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-alias -file server.cer -keystore cacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit

Please note that this is not recommended approach as this will trust the certificate only on current server/workstation and this file may be overwritten in next java upgrade. And you need to execute this step everywhere you will be deploying this application.

Although you need to do above steps to create Service proxy (Eclipse/Apache axis project generation)

Comment: I imported CA to cacerts, but this exception still pop up. Exception content has been updated in my post.

Comment: You can try to save WSDL file to locally using browser and then try to import it in eclipse.

Comment: I downloaded those XSDs to local and copy the tomcat config to workspace/server, it finally work! Even this is not a good solution like I was expected, but there is no more better option too, so I'll take this.